# Search in ListView, incorrect result on get id onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, search

I have Activiti in which there is a search for ListView. When I return the result of anything I do not use the filter, everything is fine. choose the element 520 and I get it id, but as soon as I use a filter and find the same item, get the id 0-10. Please tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!
P.S.
I am sorry for my english!

```
public class Clients extends Activity {

private ListView lv;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
EditText etInputSearch;
  DB dbSync;
  DB dbUser;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clients);
    dbSync = new DB(this);
    dbUser = new DB(this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    etInputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputSearch);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.clients_item, R.id.clients_name, dbSync.createlistClients(dbUser.getCodeAgent()));
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.d("TAG", position + " " + id);

        }
        });

    etInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            Clients.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using standard ArrayAdapter. In the realization of standard AndroidAdapter you can find following code:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

That's why you get the id quals to position. To avoid this behavior you must implement your own adapter (extending ArrayAdapter for example) and overrid getItemId method.
Or use CursorAdapter which use _id column in database as id.